# What is the meaning of "from the ground up" really?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I saw most of the dictionaries say about the same:

> from the first or elementary principles, methods, etc. to the last or most advanced; completely; thoroughly ([Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/from-the-ground-up#from-the-ground-up_1) with some examples from newspapers and books)
>
> From the most basic level to the highest level; completely: designed the house from the ground up; learned the family business from the ground up. ([Heritage](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/from+the+ground+up))

But EnglishCentral.com says the definition of the phrase is:

> starting with nothing: "The young partners built a business FROM THE GROUND UP."

I feel EnglishCentral's is more accurate. Does only "up" mean "to the highest level"?

Comment: I don't think that EnglishCentral.com is *more* accurate (in fact, I think it's less accurate); however, I'd agree that that definition, "start with nothing", is easier to understand.

Comment: Thank you for all your explanations. I've, just now, gotten an idea and found that on the net there's so many examples of both "making it from the ground up" and "made it from the ground up". I think it doesn't really matter if the project is finished or it's still in progress or even if it's just an idea for someone as an advice to use the expression, 'from the ground up', and so if it's when the project is finished, it means from nothing to the completion, but it can be also used when it's on the progress.

Answer (score 6):

Most would interpret the idiom as EnglishCentral has described it; it's commonly used in the same manner as "(to start) from scratch" or "(to start) from the beginning".

Or, [as Wiktionary describes it](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/from_the_ground_up) (emphasis added)...

> ***"from the ground up"*** (idiomatic); *From the beginning; starting with the basics, foundation, or* fundamentals.
>
> *"A bright, ambitious kid just out of technical school, learning railroading **from the ground up**."*

Answer (score 3):

The term is meant to convey the image of creating a structure, such as a building. *The ground* is the foundation, and *up* refers to adding to that foundation until the project is complete.

The meaning is *to do something completely, starting with the most basic and adding all the details.*

Similar phrases are *from scratch*, which means using basic ingredients and not partially prepared components. An example is to make a cake from flour, sugar, oil, flavoring, milk, rather than from a mix.

A related phrase is *from top to bottom* which means *thoroughly*, but does not have the same connotation of starting from the beginning and progressing through the entire project.

All of these phrases are analogies and can be applied to tasks that cover a wide range of activities, including things that have no physical components.